# Override a pointer attribute with a static array

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, c-strings

```
typedef struct chlnglck{
    friend struct chlnglck_8;
    friend struct chlnglck_10;
    friend struct chlnglck_12;

    chlng nb;
    uint64_t wt;
}chlnglck;

struct chlnglck_8 : chlnglck{
    char ress[255];
    chlnglck_8();
};

struct chlnglck_10 : chlnglck{
    char ress[1024];
    chlnglck_10();
};
```

Here is my code. I would want to know how I could mention the `ress` attribute in the parent class `chlnglck`.

Is there a way or not knowing I have to use fixed size array in the child classes?
Edit: What I meant was the following: Can I eventually declare a pointer in the parent to override it via a fixed size array in the child. (Seemed improbable but had to ask as an eventual clue)

No `std::string` please.

Comment: There's no way to "override" member variables.

Comment: By the way, the constructor function must be named the same as the structure (e.g. `chlnglck_8();`)

Comment: How "mention"? Do you mean inheriting it? And I do not understand your second-last sentence at all. Could you explain it a bit more thoroughly, please?

Comment: *No std::string please.* -- I don't understand why you think `std::string` has anything to do with your question at all.

Comment: Best way to explain what you want is to show a piece of code demonstrating how would you like to use it.

Comment: You cannot override a data member. The only thing you can override is a virtual function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry small mistake, will correct

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Its because I really have to have a fixed size to store it in a columnar file as fixed size rows, yet I don't know what size will be used and different sizes in different files will occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perhaps solve it using templates:

```
template<size_t N>
struct chlnglck
{
    chlng nb;
    uint64_t wt;

    std::array<char, N> ress;
};

struct chlnglck_8 : chlnglck<256> {};

struct chlnglck_10 : chlnglck<1024> {};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct chlnglck{
    friend struct chlnglck_8;
    friend struct chlnglck_10;
    friend struct chlnglck_12;

    uint64_t wt;
    char *ress;
}chlnglck;

struct chlnglck_8 : chlnglck{       
    chlnglck_8(){
        ress = new char[255];
    }
    ~chlnglck_8(){
        delete []ress;
    }
};

struct chlnglck_10 : chlnglck{        
    chlnglck_10(){
        ress = new char[1024];
    }
    ~chlnglck_10(){
        delete []ress;
    }
};
```

Comment: I thought for a moment about this solution but it seemed ungraceful and barbarian (however, not the barbarianest thing I used to use).

However, I like it being very static. Yet I will use the other one. Thanks a lot.